# Cloning an Azure Devops yaml Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

Azure Devops pipelines provide a clone functionality. This is super useful functionality for scaffolding pipelines. My yaml pipelines have a lot of variables, and it's difficult and error prone to reassign all of these variables from scratch.

The Azure Devops UI updated in the last week or so, and there doesn't seem to be an option to clone yaml pipelines anymore. Classic pipelines still have the clone option.

Can anyone figure out how to clone a yaml pipeline with the new UI?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I haven't used the clone feature, but have you investigated using variable groups or [variable templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#variable-templates) to make your life easier?  You can link a variable group to Azure Key Vault to facilitate secrets.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about this. I'll look into it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to help my use case. Unless I'm missing something, the variable groups need to be assigned in the yaml, and so they need to be specified in source control. The variables I specify in the pipeline are variables that can't be specified in source code.

Comment: you just specify the variable group under the variables section like: `- group: MyVarGroup`. It then brings in the variables in the variable group and keeps the secret items a secret. The only thing in your code is the variable group.  More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: I need to configure variables outside of the yaml file. Can groups be assigned to the pipeline dynamically?

Comment: yes, any variable you add to the variable group gets pulled into a new pipeline run that references that variable group.

Answer (score -1):

I've never used a cloning option in YAML. But I wouldn't use so many Azure DevOps variables which were created in the UI. You have multiple options here:

- Store the variables in your YAML file (not for secrets)
- Store the variables in a YAML template (not for secrets)
- Store the variables in a variable group (use Azure Key Vault or the Secure flag for secrets)

The variable group can be linked to multiple pipelines. But there is currently no scope available. So, if you have multiple environments, you have to name it like "myvariablegroup-dev", "myvariablegroup-prod". Hopefully, this feature to attach a variable group to an environment is coming in the near feature.

Answer (score -2):

1,You can disable the **multi-stage pipelines** feature in **preview features**

On the top right corner of the page click the user profile and choose **Preview features**

[image]

Then disable the **Multi-stage pipelines**. Then you will see the **clone** option appear again.

[image]

2,The other workaround is to [create a new pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=java%2Cbrowser%2Ctfs-2018-2) and choose to use the **Existing Azure PipelineS Yaml file** while following the wizard. (which has the same effect with cloning yaml, they use the same azure-pipelines.yml file)

[image]

Then choose the same yaml file with the original pipeline.
[image]

Comment: The pipeline has many variables. The purpose of cloning, rather than creating a new pipeline from an existing yaml file, is to preserve those variables,

Comment: I thought the variables was defined in the pipeline yaml file. But You can regain the  **clone option**  by following above workaround 1 to disable the `multi-stage pipelines` feature in preview features. You can also [report this problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to Microsoft development team and suggest to enable the clone option in preview features

Comment: Hi @Doug Did you try disabling the **multi-stage pipelines feature** to regain the clone option for yaml pipeline?